# Using indicator variables to account for outlier values

Tags: regression, outliers, categorical-encoding

I am using a fixed effects regression model to examine the relationship between diesel consumption in the US and the rates of motor accident over twenty year period.

I have been told that I need to account for outlier values for certain US states, and that indicator variables may be suitable for this. Does this seem appropriate

Comment: Is it reasonable to assume that the outlier effect is the same in the group of states under consideration? If so then an indicator should capture the effect. If this is not the case, then why is the effect heterogeneous? Is this related to other variables that you have or can measure? In that case you might need more controls and possible model interactions between these underlying variables. If there is uncertainty over whether a state belongs in the outlier group, you could model that explicitly with a hurdle like model for example.